# Why can't we use linear activation function in hidden layers?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I read a few articles which were stating that we need to add nonlinearity but it wasn't clear why we need nonlinearity and why can't we use linear activation function in hidden layers.

kindly keep math light, intuitive answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If linearities are used in every layer, effectively we end up with a linear (regression) model which is restricted in what it can represent (only linear relationships).

On the other hand the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) for neural networks assumes general (non-linear) functions which can in principle represent anything, including non-linear relationships.

So it is **not that it is forbidden**, it is simply **a poor use** of the complexity of neural networks to function as linear models since there are already other linear models to do that that are much simpler to train. Thus NNs are used mainly for general non-linear tasks and thus **have to include** non-linearities in their design (if they are **to function as such**).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am attaching article for other people's reference that I was able to find with your reference of the universal approximation theorem. [article link](https://medium.com/swlh/universal-approximation-theorem-d1a1a67c1b5b)